# ASP.NET change masterpage usercontrol from content page

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, master-pages

I'm developing my ASP.NET web app using VS2010,C#. I have a user control contained in my masterpage, and now I'm going to access my usercontrol from the content page, is it possible to change usercontrol via content page client side events? I'm going to prevent any postback

I want to simulate something like this site:

```
http://www.just-eat.co.uk/restaurants-dialacrate-w13/menu
```

when my customers click on a food, food should be added to my order basket without any postback, I think it is using a JavaScript, right?

Comment: That IS javascript. Changing the user controls are also possible. But if it is the functionality you require in the URL you gave us, then you should start delving into javascript and jQuery.

EDIT: By the way, when I encounter sites that interests me, the first thing I do is to view the source! and try to learn from there. Open up the .js files and investigate etc...

Comment: thanks Emin, yes I know it is JavaScript, I have no problem using JavaScript to dynamically create controls in my usercontrol, but I'm going to learn how to make a connection between my content page hyperlinks and my usercontrol? how can I access the usercontrol from my content page? it is my main question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am talking specific to the URL you gave in your question: If you investigate the code, the basket part in the HTML part is :

```
<div id="divBasketHeaderContent">
    <h4>
        <span id="ctl00_DesktopSideColumn_Basket_lblTxt">Your order</span>
    </h4>
</div>
```

Then, in the bundle.js;

```
function updateBasket(n, t, i) {
    document.getElementById("ctl00_DesktopSideColumn_Basket_modalProductId").value = n;
    var r = n + "#" + t + "#" + i + "#";
    __doPostBack("ctl00_DesktopSideColumn_Basket_UpdatePanel1", r)
}
```

So, he is using and asp.net updatepanel to update the basket. Although this is fine, it is not suggested, as in the background, it sends the whole page and returns a lot of data back.. [See here](http://encosia.com/why-aspnet-ajax-updatepanels-are-dangerous/) to see why..

Also in the Encosia link I've provided, you will see one of the ways how this is properly done.

You can either use [page methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/), [web services](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1231/ASP-NET-Web-Service), [plain ajax](http://danielnouri.org/notes/2011/03/13/an-ajax-page-update-mini-tutorial/), or the [web api](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/02/23/using-asp-net-web-api-with-asp-net-web-forms.aspx) to achieve what you require..

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
YouControl uc = (YouControl)Page.Master.FindControl("yourcontrolID");
```

to get access to your UC placed in your master page.

and use webservices / webmethods to get it done without any postback.

for more info on webservices [Go here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972326.aspx)

for more info on webmethods [Go here](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

Comment: thanks, can I use this approach in a JavaScript function? i.e. is it possible to write a JS function that performs these actions?

Comment: You can but then it would be tricky to maintain the state of those controls because when you use client side code to perform any action then those changes doesn't persist them self during page postbacks.